# IIS 7 and a Samba share - how do I connect

Tags: iis, samba

I'm a developer who is working on a site that needs to use some network resources that are located on a linux network that is managed by Samba (sorry, I don't know the exact mix of terms and technology).  Basically, I have a user/password provided to me by the Admin. How do I make IIS 7 use this user so I can get access to the network resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to configure it as a virtual directory for your site; give it the full path to the share, and specify the username/password that your admin gave you when you're creating the virtual directory.

There are a couple of permission problems you may run up against while doing this, which are described (along with a workaround) [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269009/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid whenever possible doing this - you can run in to really obscure networking/file permission issues (As Rainy Rat has already mentioned).

However if you have to, why not just map the Samba share as a network drive?  Nice and simple!